# How to Bind Xamarin Forms Checkbox isChecked to a dynamic bool variable?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am newbie to xamarin forms. I have a Listview containing checkboxes. I bind the checkbox "isChecked" to one of the listview's itemsource bool property. the problem is, everytime i change the bool value where the checkbox is bind, checkbox appearance has'nt change. How can i achieve that kind of approach?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DjkD.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KcT2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DjkD.png)

Comment: Have have inherited the INotifyPropertyChanged in your ListView Model? it's necessary for the Model to be inherited from INotifyPropertyChange and OnPropertyChanged method to be called at every Property's setter in order for the Binding to reflect on your property change.

Docs link for your reference
 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Try to provide your model class code also.

Comment: Hi, thank you! i am lacking on this part.

Comment: You're welcome. I too forget the NotifyPropertyChanged part many times :p. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]      Hi @Weggie Villarante. Please try this.It's work for me

```
     <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck}" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="50"></CheckBox>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
NotificationModel.cs


    public class NotificationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public string  Title { get; set; }
            public bool _IsCheck = false;

            public bool IsCheck
            {
                get
                {
                    return _IsCheck;
                }
                set
                {
                    _IsCheck = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsCheck");
                }
            }


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

NotificationViewModel.cs

 class NotificationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<NotificationModel> _Items;
        public ObservableCollection<NotificationModel> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _Items;
            }
            set
            {
                _Items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public NotificationViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<NotificationModel>();
            AddItems();
        }
        void AddItems()
        {
            _Items.Add(new NotificationModel { Title = "Info", Message = "This is only information message please ignor this one." ,IsCheck = false});
            _Items.Add(new NotificationModel { Title = "Alert", Message = "This is only Alert message please ignor this one." , IsCheck = false });
            _Items.Add(new NotificationModel { Title = "Suggesstion", Message = "This is only Suggesstion message please ignor this one." , IsCheck = false});
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tidy up this code please